# Как выполнить функцию на странице №2 при переходе со страницы №1

Tags: javascript, html, css

на странице №1 есть несколько ссылок, все они ведут на страницу 2.

```
<a href="page2.html"  onclick="water()">link number 1</a>
<a href="page2.html"  onclick="fire()">link number 2</a>
<a href="page2.html"  onclick="ground()">link number 3</a>
```

на странице №2 есть несколько блоков div, у которых изначально задано CSS свойство: display: none;

```
<div id="water">water</div>
<div id="fire">fire</div>
<div id="ground">ground</div>
```

Как можно реализовать функцию, которая при нажатии на первую ссылку будет открывать вторую страницу и  первый блок, при нажатии на вторую ссылку - вторую страницу и второй блок и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать это на HTML+CSS используя якоря и псевдоэлемент [`:target`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/target)

```
<!-- index.html -->
<a href="/two-page.html#one_block">One block</a>
<a href="/two-page.html#two_block">Two block</a>
<a href="/two-page.html#three_block">Three block</a>

<!-- two-page.html -->
<div class="hide-block" id="one_block">One block content</div>
<div class="hide-block" id="two_block">Two block content</div>
<div class="hide-block" id="three_block">Three block content</div>

<!-- CSS, лучше подключить отдельно на странице two-page.html -->
<style>
.hide-block {
  display: none;
}
.hide-block:target {
  display: block;
}
</style>
```